# Can "who" substitute for " whom" in non-restrictive relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses

> 1. Who/whom are you talking about?

> 2. Bill is a troublesome boy, whom(who?) you are talking about.

In the first sentence, **who** can substitute for **whom**. I wonder if **who** can do the same in the second sentence.

Comment: 2) is not really a sentence. Bill is **the troublesome boy** you are talking about. The who is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the relative pronoun **whom** or **who** when it is the object of the verb.

Bill is the troublesome boy **whom/who** you are talking about.

In a restrictive relative clause we can leave out the relative pronoun when it is the object of the verb.

Bill is the troublesome boy whom/who you are talking about.➜ Bill is the troublesome boy you are talking about.

We use non-restrictive relative clauses to give extra information about the person or thing. It is not necessary information. We use commas in non-restrictive relative clauses.

In a non-restrictive relative clause, the relative pronoun cannot be left out.

Bill, **whom/who** you are talking about, is a troublesome boy.

We cannot use 'Bill, you are talking about, is a troublesome boy'.

(**Edited**)

Comment: It's not a proper sentence. Bill is the troublesome boy (who) you are talking about.